# Filling Buffer with Elements of Different Lengths Without Max length - C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```
void push(struct Stack *stack, void *element)
{
    if (stack->len < stack->size)
    {
        memcpy(stack->arr + stack->len * sizeof(stack->elem_size), element, strlen((char*) element));
        printf("Pushed: %s\n", (char *)element);
        stack->len++;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Stack is full.\n");
    }
}



void display(struct Stack *stack)
{
    char** arr = (char**) stack->arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < stack->len; i++)
    {
        printf("[%s]\n", stack->arr + i * stack->elem_size);
    }
    printf("Done\n");
}
```

Hi, I'm brushing up on abstraction with C and I was wondering if anyone knew of an efficient mechanism by which I can have elements of various lengths in an array, without explicitly allocating space for them. I have allocated a buffer for the strings of 1024 bytes. Stack->arr and elment are of type void*.

The above code doesn't work correctly because the size of a type itself might not adequately predict how long the variable may be in the case of char*. The elements just aren't spaced out correctly.

Any ideas on how the pointer arithmetic might work here?

Comment: And you need an array not a singly- or doubly-linked list of pointers?

Comment: `strlen` is for null-terminated strings ***only***. If you have arbitrary data that you want to add, you need both a pointer to the data *and* its actual size. And you need to tell the stack the exact size of each element. There are two ways to solve this: Either you copy the data, and keep track of its size. Or you just store the pointer to the data, and let the user of your stack handle the size and life-time issues that might come up.

Comment: @Emily Soto, Rather than _describe_ code with "Stack->arr and elment are of type void*.", better to post the definition of `struct Stack` as  code.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you’re looking for, but if I was approaching this problem I would be tempted to build a linked list of pointers to the elements first and have a function to flatten the list out into a single chunk of data.

Each element in both the list and the array would need a header giving the data type and size in order to manage the data.

Comment: Hm, I didn't think of that approach but it sounds like it would actually work pretty well. Thanks for the answer!